# C# Getting the text between 2 characters in a string

Tags: c#, string, path

```
public String GetDirectory(String Path)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Directorul: ");
        var start = Path.IndexOf(":") + 6;
        var match2 = Path.Substring(start, Path.IndexOf(".") - start);
        return Path;      

    }
```

I need to get the path string between the 2 characters in this string:
"C:\Documents\Text.txt"

I want it to show the text between ':' and '.' at the end so :"\Documents\Text"

Comment: Why are you adding 6 to `.IndexOf(":")` in the first place? That makes zero sense to me and makes me wonder if you understand what the method does.

Comment: Why do you want that? What exactly are you trying to return from GetDirectory? [System.IO.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Path(v=vs.110).aspx) has many methods for getting a file's directory, extension, removing or changing extensions etc. Perhaps whatever you are looking for is there?

Answer (score 5):

```
int start_index = Path.IndexOf(':')+1;
int end_index = Path.LastIndexOf('.');
int length = end_index-start_index;
string directory = Path.Substring(start_index,length);
```

Comment: You should subtract the start from the second argument... (like the other anwers)

Comment: theoretically this works but we should check the case in which `:` and `.` are not found.

Answer (score 2):

Linq is always fascinating:

```
string s = string.Join("",
                       Path.SkipWhile(p => p != ':')
                           .Skip(1)
                           .TakeWhile(p => p != '.') 
                      );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use string operations, but you can also use the `System.IO.Path` functions for a - in my personal opinion - more elegant solution:

```
string path = @"C:\Documents\Text.txt";

string pathRoot = Path.GetPathRoot(path);  // pathRoot will be "C:\", for example
string result = Path.GetDirectoryName(path).Substring(pathRoot.Length - 1) +
              Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + 
              Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);       

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should return your match2 instead of the path since path will remain C:\Documents\Text.txt

```
public String GetDirectory(String Path)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Directorul: ");
    var start = Path.IndexOf(":") + 6;
    var match2 = Path.Substring(start, Path.IndexOf(".") - start);
    return match2;      

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
patch = patch.Substring(patch.IndexOf(':') + 1, patch.IndexOf('.') - 2);
```